NETBEANS 21 - The following error occurred while executing this line:/Java returned: 1
Can someone help me? I just downloaded netbeans 21 recently and I don't know why it isn't working.
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at index 26: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Jav?P\JavaApplication1\build\classes C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\21\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\21\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
I tried to reinstall netbeans and Java JDK but it didnt work.

Did you download the platform-independent binary and copied it into a directory with a fancy name like Java™? Unless you have a reason to do that, I'd recommend to get the Windows installer and install it along other programs in "C:\Program Files".

@ÁlvaroGonzález
thank you for you answer. Yes, I installed NetBeans using window-x64.exe file.
I've found the error, I named my folder Javạ instead of Java.
Again, thank you for your answer and sorry for the inconvenience.

Still, it isn't a good idea to install applications on the desktop. The default Program Folder location is designed for that, and has the appropriate permissions.
